# array assignment using php end does not work as expected

Tags: php

If I have an array:

```
[
   start => 2018-01-01 12:00
   end   => 2018-01-01 15:00
],
[
   start => 2018-01-01 12:00
   end   => 2018-01-01 17:00
],
```

This array can have any number of start and end dates, and I will need to filter each day  by their start and end time.  Ie, 2018-01-01 could have 5 entries with different start and end times.

I need to end up with a single array with the earlier start time, and the LATEST end time:

```
[
   start => 2018-01-01 12:00
   end   => 2018-01-01 17:00
]
```

In my loop, I'm comparing the end times and if the second is larger than the first, I want to replace the value of `end` to this new one:

```
$newArr[] = $dates[0];

foreach($dates as $date) {
    if ($date['end'] > end($newArr)['end'] {
       end($newArr)['end'] = $date['end']
    }
}
```

For some reason, this assignment is not actually working - it remains as the initial setting `end => 15:00`

Hope that's clear :)

Comment: I suppose the synax errors are only in this snippet but not in original code?

Comment: Why do you even use `end` function?

Comment: Do you have error reporting turned to on?Fix the syntax and replace end($newArr)) for $newArr

Comment: you don't need the `end($newArr)`. It's working if you use `$newArr[0]['end']`

Comment: this is snippet but its not syntax errors - its running fine but its simply not doing the assignment even though I can see it gets into that condition

Comment: It is not running fine. Add those line in the beginning of your script : ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
    error_reporting(E_ALL);

Comment: @Jeff i'm using `end` because the `$newArr` will have more additions, it won't always be `[0]` - so I use `end` to make sure it replaces the latest

Comment: the problem is, that end() returns the value, not a reference.

Comment: maybe use $newArr[max(array_keys($newArr)]['end'] instead of end()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Problem is, that `end()` returns a value, not a reference.
By pointing manually to the last index it would work as expected:

```
$newArr[] = $dates[0];

foreach($dates as $date) {
    if ($date['end'] > $newArr[max(array_keys($newArr))]['end']) {
       $newArr[max(array_keys($newArr))]['end'] = $date['end'];
    }
}

echo "<pre>";       
var_dump($newArr);
echo "</pre>";
```

Working snippet: https://3v4l.org/RCqA0

Comment: If the keys change with unset or something this solution (using count or sizeof-1) will break the code.

Answer (score 0):

No reason to use `end()` in either place since you want only one element in the result:

```
$newArr[] = $dates[0];

foreach($dates as $date) {
    if ($date['end'] > $newArr[0]['end']) {
       $newArr[0]['end'] = $date['end'];
    }
    if ($date['start'] < $newArr[0]['start']) {
       $newArr[0]['start'] = $date['start'];
    }
}
```

Also, your current code only checks and adds `end` not `start`.

Answer (score -1):

You might want to try to convert datetime to timestamp before doing the comparison.

$timestamp['end'] = strtotime($date['end']);